# A two-thread problem that the program never exit as I expect

Tags: c++, multithreading

I designed a simple logging component, but I encountered some problems. The `Logging` object will create a thread to save logs from buffer in the background. The `main` thread writes logs into buffer. However, because I use `pthread_detach`, the `main` thread will exit even if the `Logging` thread is still working.

I use `pthread_cond_t` to solve that problem. I set the `LastWriteTime`, which represents the last time when main thread wrote to the log. If there has been no log for a period of time, the Logging thread will notify the main thread.

But the program blocks and never exits.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;
int64_t get_current_millis(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (int64_t)tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
}

void *run(void *args);

class Logging
{
public:
    static Logging *LoggingPtr;
    pthread_mutex_t ExitMutex;
    pthread_cond_t ExitCond;
    struct timeval LastWriteTime;
    Logging() : ExitMutex(PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER), ExitCond(PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER)
    {
        pthread_t pid;
        pthread_create(&pid, NULL, run, NULL);
        pthread_detach(pid);
    }

    bool CheckExpired(struct timeval lastWriteTime, size_t wait_time)
    {
        struct timeval now;
        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        long now_sec = now.tv_sec * 1000 + now.tv_usec / 1000;
        long last_sec = lastWriteTime.tv_sec * 1000 + lastWriteTime.tv_usec / 1000;

        // expired time: wait_time(ms)
        return now_sec - last_sec > wait_time ? true : false;
    }

    void Save()
    {
        cout << "in the save" << endl;
        while (true)
        {
            if (CheckExpired(LastWriteTime, 3000))
            {
                pthread_cond_signal(&ExitCond);
            }
        }
    }

    static Logging *Init()
    {
        while (!LoggingPtr)
        {
            LoggingPtr = new Logging();
        }
        return LoggingPtr;
    }

    void Append()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&ExitMutex);
            gettimeofday(&LastWriteTime, NULL);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&ExitMutex);
        }
    }

    void Exit()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (CheckExpired(LastWriteTime, 3000))
            {
                pthread_cond_signal(&ExitCond);
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&ExitMutex);
        // 3000 means that the wait_time is 3s
        while (!CheckExpired(this->LastWriteTime, 3000))
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&ExitCond, &ExitMutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&ExitMutex);
    }
};

void *run(void *args)
{
    Logging::Init()->Save();
    return NULL;
}

Logging *Logging::LoggingPtr = nullptr;

int main()
{
    uint64_t start_ts = get_current_millis();

    Logging LOG;
    LOG.Append();

    LOG.Exit();

    uint64_t end_ts = get_current_millis();
    std::cout << "wait " << (end_ts - start_ts) / 1000 << "s" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This begs the question why detach? This is exactly the use case `join` was intended to solve.

Comment: @user4581301, I try what you say but it don't work.

Comment: `pthread` has a C API. Of course, it can be used in C++ on platforms where it is supported. But: C++ provides [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) which even works where `pthread` is not available (or, at least, not usual) like e.g. in Windows / MSVC. Not to mention, that `std::thread` has a C++ API (as part of the standard C++ library) and provides some extras to write safer code more conveniently.

Comment: @夜听风雨声 when doing the right thing doesn't work you should stop and figure out why. Trying to beat the wrong solution into working condition is usually more complicated and frustrating.